# Trouble Deleting Partition from disk utility after uninstalling Asahi Linux in Macbook

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I am using a Macbook M1 2020.

I followed the steps given in the following video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMnWTq2H-N0&t=146s

At time stamp 2:05, Mr. Macintosh gives the command given below.

```
diskutil eraseVolume JHES+ drive /dev/disk0s4
```

For me, this command failed and issued the following error message.

```
JHES+ does not appear to be a valid file system format
```

Even though Mr. Macintosh in the video specifically said to use this command before deleting the partitions in Disk Utility, I went ahead and did the Disk Utility bit anyway. Now, I am stuck with an almost 65.5 Gb partition, which I can't delete because the "-" button is greyed out.

After going back to the video and further research, I tried the following command, which worked without errors.

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ drive /dev/disk0s6
```

However, Disk Utility still will not erase the partition.

Can anyone please help me?

I wish to delete `disk0s6` in the screenshot shown below.
[image: Terminal image showing all partitions, i wish to delete disk0s6]

Comment: The video clearly shows `JHFS+` where you entered `JHES+`.

Comment: Based on your image, you probably want `diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ drive2 /dev/disk0s3`. I should point out that the NAME for the first and last partitions of `disk0` shown in your image do not seem to match what is shown in the video.

Comment: @DavidAnderson THANK YOU SO MUCH! Yes you were right, it should have been JHFS+